# Background-Image Scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website and I want the background-image to scale with the page and always be the correct aspect ratio. The problem with `background-size: cover` or `contain` is that while it adjusts the width dimension correctly, if you have a browser in an aspect ratio that is taller than the background image, it begins to tile vertically.

So I thought I would write a jQuery function to get around this, and it works great for me:

```
$(window).resize(resizeBg);

function resizeBg(){
    var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var aspectRatio = winWidth/winHeight;
    var imageRatio = 1920/1200;
    if(aspectRatio < imageRatio)
        $("body").css("background-size", "auto " + winHeight + "px");
    else
        $("body").css("background-size", winWidth + "px auto");
}
resizeBg();
```

But before I put this live I just wanted to ask if anyone knows of better ways to do this or  ways in which I can clean up this function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few different ways to accomplish this. I typically try and stick with css. Here is just one css method.

html

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

css

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

On a csstricks.com post it explores all the various ways and includes the pros and cons + demos. I found it useful when I was exploring this matter.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Relevant code example should be included in your answer since there's no guarantee that link will always work.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't use the code above but the CSS3 way works a treat. This website is for a particular demographic I can assue will not be using less than IE9. So this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`background-size: auto;` should work fine here, you just need to specify `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-position: center` as well. Hope this helps.